# Is it possible to change DOM without using append() or appendTo()

Tags: jquery

I am working on a script that utilizes jQuery UI's drag/drop functionality. When i drag an item from one area to another I would like to update the DOM by associating the element with the dropped area and not the original where it was created initially. I could use appendTo() but it creates a jump when I drop the item and i need it to remain in the position where it was dragged to.

Is there an alternative to update the DOM?

Comment: Whoever gave -1: do you know the answer? Care to share with the rest?

Comment: Doesn't jQuery UI's drag/drop automatically append the item to the drop-element?

Comment: No it keeps the DOM in the same area... I tried this: $( ".droppable" ).droppable({   
    drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $(ui.draggable).appendTo($( this ));
}});
 but when the element is appended to the new area it does not stay in the place where i drop it, but jumps within the area where it was dropped. Weird...

Answer (score 2):

The alternative to append the DOM would be `.insertAfter()` `.insertBefore()` `.add()` `.after()` `.before()` `.clone()` `.detach()` et-al

for more details visit [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/)

Comment: perhaps more specifically: [Manipulation category](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/)

Comment: So, I'm still not sure, if i drag the item from #area1 to #area2, how do I update the DOM without making it the item "jump" on drop? I guess I need to change the dom WHILE DRAGGING BEFORE DROPPING? I'm more confused not then before i started...

Comment: Thanks @Wiseguy, I'll look through the options.